# How to know if i have vertical scroll bars in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

how to detect if my angular page have vertical scrollbars dynamically?
i can add or remove item from a ng-template and i must show a button whether i have vertical scrollbar or hide if not, and if i remove a template must check if i still have bars, if not have i must hide a button.

i've tryed this code below, but when i render the html i got the error

.TS

```
async pageHaveScrollBars() {
        const elem = document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
        const scrollElement = await (elem as any).getScrollElement();
        return scrollElement.scrollHeight > elem.offsetHeight;
    }
```

.HTML

```
<ion-button color="primary" (click)="scroll(showScrollDownButton, showScrollUpButton)" *ngIf="pageHaveScrollBars() |async " class="button_rounded">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" *ngIf="showScrollDownButton"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"  *ngIf="showScrollUpButton"></i>
                </ion-button>
```

Comment: If there is a scrollbar, I guess that the bottom of the page is not visible. So, maybe you can do something with [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). You will be notified when the bottom of the page becomes visible/invisible.

Comment: maybe, you can calculate if the height of body is more then 100vh..i think could work